# How to docker-compose an image that refers to an existing image and add a argument-named file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a container 'pepsr' we build at work which makes use of a generic configuration file 'install.config.json'.
This config file contains all the necessary information that enables pepsr to know the  specifics of the very host it is ran on.

I'd like to make a compose yml that simply takes the pepsr image and COPY say 'harvard.installation.config.json' as 'installation.config.json' so that the final container knows it runs on 'harvard'.

The resulting builder script I dream of, is as follows:

```
$ ./makeRelease harvard
```

which invokes `docker-compose build`.

As a result, the script should produce the image named 'pepsr-hardvard'.

In other words, the `makeRelease.sh` script should make `docker-compose` does the following:

1. take the `nameOfTheInstallation` from the argument;
2. take the existing generic image 'pepsr';
3. `COPY <nameOfTheInstallation>.installation.config.json installation.config.json`
4. Set the name of the container as `pepsr-<nameOfTheInstallation>`

Important: We waived the --volume option to refer to the config file because we want an all-in-one resulting container:

1. that's easy to pull and run;
2. **we want to update the config file** over time when new features come in.

Any other option is welcome :-)

Comment: A bind-mounted host file is usually the right answer for this.  How similar are the various config files, though?  Are they identical up to a couple of parameters you could substitute at container-startup time?

Comment: They are quite heavy, apart of the data model, almost all the values vary from one intall to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-compose doesn't do what you are asking for. You need a `Dockerfile` for that.

```
FROM pepsr
ARG RELEASE_NAME
COPY ${RELEASE_NAME}.installation.config.json installation.config.json
```

Then you could use that in your docker-compose.yaml.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  pepsr-release:
    image: "myregistry.io/pepsr-${RELEASE_NAME}:${RELEASE_TAG}"
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        RELEASE_NAME:
```

Docker compose will read a `.env file`, if it's present in your directory, and also use any variable you have currently set in your `shell` (shell takes precedence if both are set). If you use such a variable as `build arg` with empty value, compose will use the value of the env variable it found.

So you could either create such an `.env file` next to the compose file, containing the `RELEASE_NAME` or set it in the shell like shown below.

```sh
export RELEASE_NAME="harvard"
export RELEASE_TAG="0.0.1"
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

You can even use the env variables to name the image or tag the image  like shown above.

For this example, need a docker-compose.yaml and a Dockerfile next to each other.

```
.
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Building an image for each host seems a bit non-Docker-like, since one of the strengths of Docker is that your image can run anywhere unchanged.

If you don't want to use volumes or bind-mounts, then the only thing I can think of is piping the file into the container. Something like this

```
$ cat harvard.installation.config.json | docker run --rm -i <myimage>
```

Then you'll be able to read the configuration file from stdin in your image.

Comment: I should have mentioned that beyond being simple to deploy, the fact that we want the config file inside de container is because we may want to update the config file over time (and take advantage of k8s for the CI/CD)

Comment: In a Kubernetes context, you can use a ConfigMap for this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with the following solution: I wrote two docker files:

- For Pepsr generic : `Dockerfile.pepsr.generic` that build the whole pepsr software and container image but *has no CMD*;
- For Pepsr installation: `Dockerfile.pepsr.installation` that simply copy the given installation configuration file plus `CMD npm start` to start the perpsr generic nodeJs app.

My compose file `docker-compose.yml` is as follows:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  pepsr-generic:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pepsr.generic
      context: .
    image: <myrepo>/pepsr-generic
    container_name: pepsr-generic
    network_mode: host
    restart: always

  pepsr-install:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pepsr.installation.release
      context: .
      args:
        INSTALLATION_NAME:
    hostname:  pepsr-${INSTALLATION_NAME}
    network_mode: host
    image: <myrepo>/pepsr-${INSTALLATION_NAME}
    container_name: pepsr-${INSTALLATION_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: 
      - pepsr-generic
```

Basically, my compose says:

1. The pepsr-generic builds against its own provided Dockerfile and it's given an image name and a container name.
2. The pepsr-install builds against its own Dockerfile, takes an argument I name INSTALLATION_NAME (its value comes form the ENV variable) and its image and container name are given according to it. One very important thing is that I declare that this container depends on the other one (pepsr-generic).

Finally, to ease the build I provide a bash script that sets the `INSTALLATION_NAME` environment variable to be passed to docker-compose as follows (a streamlined version):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
module=" dockerPepsrMakeRelease"
TODAY=$(TZ=":GMT" date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
echo "  ____"
echo " |  _ \ ___ _ __  ___ _ __ "
echo " | |_) / _ \ '_ \/ __| '__|"
echo " |  __/  __/ |_) \__ \ |   "
echo " |_|   \___| .__/|___/_|   "
echo "           |_|             "
echo "---------------------------"
echo PEPSR: Release manager for Docker

export INSTALL_NAME=$1

docker-compose build
retVal=$?

if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo " $module: error: could not docker-compose build. Aborted"
    exit 1
fi

echo " $module: image completed."
exit 0
```